Oh no! IO! Concurrency issues with virtual threads, HikariCP, and Spring Boot JDBC (Postgres)
I have run into an issue when using the following technologies.

PostgreSQL run through a docker container
Project Loom
Spring Boot 3.3.4
Java 21
Spring Boot Starter JDBC (which includes HikariCp - who I believe to be the source of the issue)
Spring Boot Starter JPA

And obviously, a litany of other things. I can provide a POM on request, but I don't think it'll be helpful. My postgres driver is UTD, as is all my versions.
The core issue is when running concurrent operations at high speeds, I am running into IO issues with HikariCp, when trying to save items to my database. I'm not totally sure what to do.
In my microservice's logs:
2024-09-19T18:50:51.617-04:00  WARN 10060 --- [virtual-ingest] [    virtual-342] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@28b26c3f marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.

**In Docker Logs for PG (repeated, constantly):
**
2024-09-19 22:50:51.807 UTC [412] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction


My code (I haven't gone back to clean this up yet):
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void startStructures()
    {
        try (var outerScope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure())
        {
            sqsConfig.getQueues().forEach(queue -> outerScope.fork(() -> {
                processQueueMessages(queue);
                return null;
            }));
            outerScope.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            log.error("Processing interrupted", e);
        }
    }

    private void processQueueMessages(String queue)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try (var innerScope = new StructuredTaskScope.ShutdownOnFailure())
            {
                List<Message> messages = retrieveMessages(queue);
                if (messages.isEmpty())
                {
                    log.info("No messages in queue: {}, sleeping...", queue);
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (Message message : messages)
                    {
                        innerScope.fork(() -> {
                            processMessage(queue, message);
                            return null;
                        });
                    }
                    innerScope.join();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                log.error("Queue processing interrupted", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Message> retrieveMessages(String queue)
    {
        var url = awsConfig.getBaseUrl() + queue;
        ReceiveMessageRequest request = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
                                                             .queueUrl(url)
                                                             .maxNumberOfMessages(10)
                                                             .waitTimeSeconds(
                                                                 10)
                                                             .build();

        ReceiveMessageResponse response = sqsClient.receiveMessage(request);
        return response.messages();
    }

    private void processMessage(String queue, Message message) throws JsonProcessingException
    {

        log.info("Processing message from queue {}: {}", queue, message.messageId());

        JsonNode node = nodeBuilderService.buildNode(message);
        distributionService.handleSqsNotification(node);
        deleteMessage(queue, message);
    }

    private void deleteMessage(String queue, Message message)
    {
        var url = awsConfig.getBaseUrl() + queue;
        sqsClient.deleteMessage(builder -> builder.queueUrl(url).receiptHandle(message.receiptHandle()));

        int remainingMessages = getMessageCount(queue);
        log.info(
            "Deleted message: {}. Approximate {} messages remaining in the queue.", message.messageId(),
            remainingMessages
        );
    }

    public int getMessageCount(String queueName)
    {
        var url = awsConfig.getBaseUrl() + queueName;

        GetQueueAttributesRequest request = GetQueueAttributesRequest.builder()
                                                                     .queueUrl(url)
                                                                     .attributeNames(
                                                                         QueueAttributeName.APPROXIMATE_NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES)
                                                                     .build();

        return Integer.parseInt(
            sqsClient.getQueueAttributes(request)
                     .attributes()
                     .get(QueueAttributeName.APPROXIMATE_NUMBER_OF_MESSAGES)
        );
    }

In the processing of messages, my code eventually hits this method:
@Transactional
    public void process(String filename, InputStream stream)
    throws IOException
    {
        byte[] bytes = getBytesFromInputStream(stream, filename);

        List<SurfaceObservation> observations = decoder.beginSynopticDecoders(bytes, filename);
        repository.saveAllAndFlush(observations);
    }

Which is where the error occurs.
I have tried forcing this onto a platform thread, but I believe this is related to HikariCP's lack of support for virtual threads, even in current versions. I watched JEP cafe on my scopes—and I'm wondering if anyone can help me answer a few questions.

Am I doing anything blatantly wrong? I'm migrating from async patterns, and want to never use them again, so there's a good chance I don't know what I should be doing.
I am wondering if ExtentLocal can help. I think the problem in Hikari might be related to their use of ThreadLocal. but again, new to this stuff.
Do I have to ditch spring jdbc? What would I use instead? R2DBC as of (I'm pretty sure) writing this still does not have a good ORM system, even with Hibernate reactive.

I tried Platform threads, I tried a scope for just the DB transactions. I tried a lot of stuff for hours and have that code-brain where now I'm not even sure what I tried. I even tried to have chatGPT help me, and as expected, it could not.


Not that I can spot in your code off the top of my head. Question: do you use Thread Interruption to control the execution in normal flow of events or your catching of InterruptedException  is just usual "expecting unexpected"? Whether outerScope makes sense depends on answer.  By async you meant Reactive? WebFlux/Mono? 2. Doubt so. Don't see how usage of TLs with VTs could lead to exceptions. 3. Not quite follow. Whyn't to use Spring Data JPA native to Spring Boot, which is atop of Hibernate? 0. PSQLException: does not seem to be related to VTs/multithreading/asyncing and such (?)


Thanks for the response! Thread interruption is the expecting unexpected, and I was (previously) using a completable future pattern, not flux. I ended up bypassing or not having to deal with this issue by implementing a redis cache on the overwhelmed db threads. It's an ok solution while we work through the full pattern, but thanks a ton for the comment and confirming my code isn't at least obviously trash ;). I do use JPA as well - I think the virtual thread issue was switch-away from transactions getting closed and hibernate flagging the failures, disallowing them to continue later.

No problem, my pleasure. If you don't use thread interruption as a mean of thread interaction (which is always possible but less effective than Object.notify, LockSupport.unpark, spinning w/volatile lookup) then outerScope is of no much benefit - it seems to me that processQueueMessages is never-ending under normal circumstances method, but it never hurts to use STS/VT for it. Other than that I don't see anything wrong VT-wise in the snippets you provided. If downstream/upstack methods use synchronized, it can cause VT pinning,  but it's altogether different topic.

I am marking this as answered as I am no longer experiencing the problem after implementing a Redis cache, but I do believe Hikari has issues in handling virtual-thread utilizing, highly concurrent applications and will watch to see if any better solution comes up.

Redis cache can be of course a game changer. If I were you, however, I'd try to attack the issue from the SQL exception end. But if you suspect Hikari pool, you could try another JDBC connection pool implementations.  Didn't get you on this statement: "the virtual thread issue was switch-away from transactions getting closed and hibernate flagging the failures". VT and Hibernate transactions seem to me unrelated.
